# Closed form expression for summation of P(n, k)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I was wondering if there is a closed form expression for the following:

\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^d P(n,k) \cdot n^{n-k} 
\end{equation}

This expression came up while analyzing an algorithm. The analysis is rather lengthy, but if asked, I can provide that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that you can write $$ \sum_{k=1}^d \frac{n!}{k!} n^{n-k} = n! n^n \sum_{k=1}^d \frac{(1/n)^{k}}{k!}. $$ The latter sum has no closed form I believe, but it approaches $e^{1/n}-1$ relatively quickly as $d$ grows larger.

Comment: @MisterRiemann See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D1+to+d+of+(1%2Fn)%5Ek%2Fk! for a closed form of the sum in your comment.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Note the factorial in the denominator.

Comment: @MisterRiemann The comment formatted improperly, which left out the exclamation point in the link. Try [this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D1+to+d+of+(1%2Fn)%5Ek%2Fk!). Basically, it says $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(1/n)^k}{k!}=\frac{e^{1/n} \Gamma(d+1,1/n)}{\Gamma(d+1)}-1$$

Comment: @NobleMushtak Very nice!

Comment: @MisterRiemann, NobleMushtak: very nice indeed, thank you!!

Comment: @MisterRiemann You have $P(n,k)=n!/k!$ in your first comment, I think it should be $n!/(n-k)!$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Ah, indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^d \frac{n! }{(n-k)!}n^{n-k}=e^n \Gamma (n+1,n)-e^n n!\frac{ \Gamma (n-d,n)}{\Gamma(n-d)}-n^n$$ where appears the complete and incomplete gamma functions.